# Convert EXIF data to how it should looks like

Tags: php, exif

According to PHP, the EXIF information for a image is `20/10` for F-number, `51/10` for focal length, and `10/150` for exposure. This is not how these values should look like! It should looks like `F/2` for F-number, `5, mm` for focal length, and `1/150` for exposure. These values are just some examples! Please see [this link](http://www.exiv2.org/sample.html) for how I really mean how it should looks like. Note that I will **not** use any third party software! Just pure PHP.

Is it possible to convert these values (for example `20/10`) to the real values (for example `F/2`) in PHP? If yes, how can I convert them?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The following code convert `150/10` to 150 seconds which is 2 minutes and 30 seconds. This is wrong because I took the photo with 15 seconds shutter. How can I make it to calculate to the correct amount of seconds?

```
list($d1, $d2) = str_split('/', 'P1220379.JPG');

if($d1 > 0 AND $d2 > 0) {
    $e = $d1 / $d2;
} else {
    $e = 'P1220379.JPG';
}

if($e < 1 AND $e > 0) {
    $e = '1/'.round(1 / $e, 0).' sekunder';
} else {
    $e = round($e, 1).' sekunder';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"drpain" on this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) says

> Please note that when resizing images with GD and most image
>   processing scripts or applications you will loose the EXIF
>   information.What I did as a workaround is book this information into
>   MySQL before I re-size images.

His little program below

```
<?php

$camera = cameraUsed("/img/myphoto.jpg");
echo "Camera Used: " . $camera['make'] . " " . $camera['model'] . "<br />";
echo "Exposure Time: " . $camera['exposure'] . "<br />";
echo "Aperture: " . $camera['aperture'] . "<br />";
echo "ISO: " . $camera['iso'] . "<br />";
echo "Date Taken: " . $camera['date'] . "<br />";

?>
```

does produce these numbers in correct format, *according to him*

Will display the following, depending on the data:

```
Camera Used: SONY DSC-S930
Exposure Time: 1/400
Aperture: f/4.3
ISO: 100
Date Taken: 2010:12:10 18:18:45
```

Comment: But this didn't solve my problem with the focal length. How can I convert focal length to its proper value?

Comment: Did you try this code against your unedited pictures and see what output it gives?

Comment: Yes. The code only "convert" F-number (aperture) and exposure time. Not focal length :/

Comment: can't find focal length on that page. May be have to dig a little into exif fields and try to figure out the correct field name?

Comment: I have found some lines of code that calculates the shutter time for a photo but it shows wrong amount of seconds. Please see my edit.

Comment: focal length isn't to do with time, it's the adjustment on the lens. i.e. if you have a 16 - 210mm variable lens, and you extend it to the maximum position, it will have a focal length of 2100/10, which is literally the sum you need to work out the mm. it is 2100 / 10 = 210mm.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution in kotlin if anyone needs

```
fun convertShutterSpeed(value: String?): String {
    if (value.isNullOrBlank()) {
        return ""
    }
    val split = value.split("/")
    val ed: Float = split[0].toFloat()
    val ed1: Float = split[1].toFloat()

    val fl = ed / ed1

    return if (ed < 0) {
        Math.round(1 / Math.pow(2.toDouble(), fl.toDouble())).toString() + "s"
    } else {
        "1/" + Math.round(Math.pow(2.toDouble(), fl.toDouble()))
    }
}
```

And here are some tests

```
@Test
fun convertShutterSpeed() {
    assertEquals("1/8", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("3/1"))
    assertEquals("1/10", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("3321928/1000000"))
    assertEquals("1/20", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("4321928/1000000"))
    assertEquals("1/125", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("6965784f/1000000"))
    assertEquals("1/250", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("7965784/1000000"))
    assertEquals("1/320", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("8321928/1000000"))
    assertEquals("1/400", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("8643856/1000000"))
    assertEquals("1/640", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("9321928/1000000"))
    assertEquals("1/800", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("9643856/1000000"))
    assertEquals("1/1000", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("9965784/1000000"))
    assertEquals("2s", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("-1/1"))
    assertEquals("6s", imageExif.convertShutterSpeed("-2584963/1000000"))
}
```

Values that I got is from Canon images, but it works for other camera models as well.